# Selenium: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: selenium

When I try to click on a textarea selenium keeps telling me that the element is not visible, even though I can clearly see it. Besides, if I try to set its text it says "Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated".

Comment: Instead of `Thread.Sleep()` or `ImplicitWait` induce `ExplicitWait`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting wait time:

e.g.

```
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

      driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

      driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

and/or

```
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

If these do not work add to them:

```
       IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

       js.ExecuteScript("var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');" + "evt.initMouseEvent('click',true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0,null);" + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);", driver.FindElement(By.XPath("your element")));
```

Comment: You can always increase it. Also check internet speed as it might also prevent selenium webdriver finding the element. Did you try Implicit wait?

Comment: I have used WebUI.waitForElementVisible